# How do I control where new Forth words will be compiled?

Tags: forth, gforth

Is there a way to change what `HERE` points to, or some other way to make sure that the next definition I compile will end up in some special location? Or can I copy a definition to somewhere else once it's made? Ideally I'd want a solution in ANS Forth, but something Gforth-specific is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ALLOT](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans6.htm#6.1.0710) to move the data space pointer in both directions:

```
: here! ( a -- )   here - allot ;
```

As for gforth, this simpler version should work:

```
: here!   dp ! ;
```

Having said this, [HERE](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans6.htm#6.1.1650) isn't necessarily where new words will be compiled.  HERE points to *data space*, whereas definitions are written to *name space* and *code space*.  However, in a traditional design like Gforth, the three are a single contiguous region.  See [DPANS94 3.3](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans3.htm#3.3).

Comment: dp is more or less what I was looking for. How should I go about finding such things?

Comment: Read lots of Forth source code (implementations and applications), Forth magazines (archived), internet discussions (comp.lang.forth).

Comment: So there isn't a glossary of gforth-specific words?

Comment: There is a glossary, but it doesn't include DP: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Word-Index.html

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. I take it there isn't a glossary that *does* include it?

Comment: Well, there's this: http://www.dwheeler.com/6502/fig-forth-glossary.txt which is probably where Gforth got it from.